# How to prove this weighted sum inequality with non-increasing sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequalities, combinatorial-optimization, elementary-proofs

### Problem

I have two non-increasing sequences, $X = (x_1, x_3, x_5, \ldots, x_{n-1})$ and $Y = (y_1, y_3, y_5, \ldots, y_{n -1})$, $n$ is an even integer. I want to prove this inequality:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} w_{2i-1} x_{2i-1} \geq \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} w_{2i-1} y_{2i-1}\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
where $w_i = p^{i+1} + \ldots + p^n$, and $p$ is a real number in range (0,1].

There are some inequalities between $X$ and $Y$:

1. $\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} x_{2i-1} \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} y_{2i-1} $.
2. $x_1 \geq \frac{1}{2} y_i$ for all $ i \in \{1, 3, \ldots, n-1\}$.
3. $x_i$ and $y_i$ are positive (or non-negative) for all $i$.

### What have I tried

I frist ignored the specific value of $w_i$, and try to prove inequality \eqref{1} assuming $(w_1, w_3, \ldots, w_{n-1})$ is a general non-increasing sequence. However, I found the inequality does not hold for this general setting. I found a counter example.

So I tried to prove inequality \eqref{1} with the given $w_i = p^{i+1} + \cdots + p^n$. To deal with this very specific $w_i$ I tried to do many case distinctions, which make things unclear and messy. I need to find a more promising direction to prove \eqref{1}.

### Additional inequalities between $X$ and $Y$

Maybe given additional inequalities between $X$ and $Y$, inequality \eqref{1} will hold, and the proof will be easier?

Actually my $X$ and $Y$ are edge-weights of two matchings of a complete graph. I might be able to find more inequalities between $X$ and $Y$. But I need a promising direction to know what additional inequalities I need to provide.

### General Inquiry:

May I request recommendations on

1. Pertinent issues I can explore for reference?
2. Overall guidance on the potential directions to substantiate \eqref{1}.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible approach: Treat $p$ (and thus all $w_i$) as constant, and regard the $x_i$ and $y_i$ as variables. Then, conditions 1, 2 and 3 as well as the nondecreasingness requirement are linear inequalities that define a polyhedron -- actually a polyhedral cone. Your goal is to prove a linear inequality. So it suffices to prove this inequality for the generators of the cone. If you can find the generators (or at least a set of points that contains the generators), then this strategy can make things very easy.

Comment: Note that your conditions 2 and 1 are simply saying that $2x_1 \geq y_1$ and $2y_1 \geq x_1$, assuming the nondecreasingness.

Comment: Things get a bit simpler if you fix $x_1$ and $y_1$, so you are looking at the polytope defined by the inequalities $x_1 \geq x_3 \geq x_5 \geq \cdots \geq x_{2n-1}$ and $y_1 \geq y_3 \geq y_5 \geq \cdots \geq y_{2n-1}$ and $x_1 + x_3 + \cdots + x_{2n-1} \geq y_1 + y_3 + \cdots + y_{2n-1}$. My guess is that its vertices should not be hard to compute.

Comment: Wait, should condition 3 really say $x_1 \geq \dfrac12 x_i$, or rather $y_1 \geq \dfrac12 x_i$ ?

Comment: Condition 3 is $x_1 \geq \frac{1}{2} x_i$.  Condition 2 and 3 is saying $x_1$ is the largest element among all $X$ and $Y$.  @darijgrinberg

Comment: Ah, so the $x_i$ and $y_i$ can be negative?

Comment: No, all x_i and y_i  are positive.

Comment: In that case, Condition 3 is redundant, since the non-increasingness already implies $x_1 \geq x_i \geq \dfrac12 x_i$.

Comment: You are right! I will edit the problem description. Thank you!

Comment: So, is condition 2 simply $x_1\geq y_1/2$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Right, $x_1 \geq \frac{1}{2}y_1$, and since $y_i$ is a non-increasing sequence, $x_1 \geq  \frac{1}{2} y_i$ for all $i$.